# How to reference the default DataSource from another one?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, instantiation

I am writing a bean that wraps a DataSource to add some internal functionality to it. It seems that MyDataSource is trying to use itself in the constructor. My new class is shown below:

```java
@Component
public class MyDataSource implements DataSource {

  public MyDataSource(DataSource wrapped) {
    // do something...
  }

}
```

When I try to run the application I get:

> Error creating bean with name 'myDataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

I don't control the creation of the normal DataSource at all, so it doesn't have a `Qualifier` or `@Primary`. I do control MyDataSource.

How do I tell my bean that it should use "the other DataSource" instead, and not itself during instantiation?

Comment: The more I think about this issue, the more I think the original dataSource should not be a bean at all, but a POJO. I'm wondering if I can use it and "deregister" it right away.

Answer (score 2):

This is common when your custom bean and the original bean are of the same interface type, like `DataSource` in your case. To solve this issue, you need to guide Spring on which bean to inject where, ensuring that your `MyDataSource` does not attempt to wrap itself, causing a circular reference.

There are several strategies to resolve this, but one common approach is to use `@Qualifier` annotation or defining your bean with a specific method and using `@Primary`. However, as you mentioned that you do not control the creation of the original `DataSource` and it does not have a `@Qualifier` or `@Primary`, we need to find another way.

A practical approach in your situation is to define an @Configuration class that explicitly configures your custom DataSource and uses it to wrap the existing DataSource bean.

- Remove `@Component` from `MyDataSource`. This prevents Spring from trying to instantiate it automatically.
- Create a Configuration Class. In this class, you will manually configure `MyDataSource` and inject the existing `DataSource`.

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyDataSource myDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        // Ensure that the dataSource bean injected here is the original DataSource
        // and not your MyDataSource. Spring should handle this automatically
        // since MyDataSource is now being created manually in this configuration.
        return new MyDataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```

This configuration explicitly declares that your `MyDataSource` should wrap the `DataSource` bean that Spring automatically configures. Since `MyDataSource` is no longer annotated with `@Component`, Spring will not try to instantiate it automatically, thus avoiding the circular reference.

Comment: Unfortunately it crashes with the same error: Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?: `myDataSource defined in class path resource [app/DataSourceConfig.class]`. Seems like the parameter is still itself.

Comment: Make sure you've adjusted from the `@Component` error to using `@Configuration` and `@Bean` forms